# I think wrong Jack version Jack1 instead of Jack2 (Ubuntu14. Studio)

Tags: sound, package-management

I had lots of problems with my external firewire audio card in Ubuntu so I did fixed it with lots of help from my friends of Jack-ffado and jack-devel.

But now I try to install new software and if I try to do the configure then at the end it says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libjack-dev : Depends: libjack0 (= 1:0.121.3+20120418git75e3e20b-2.1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I try to install `libjack2-dev` but I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package libjack2-dev
```

So now I think I mixed up Jack1 and Jack2 if I am not mistaken Ubuntu 14 needs Jack2?

How can I fix this?

My info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS  
Release:    14.04  
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 2):

The package you are looking for is [`libjack-jackd2-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libjack-jackd2-dev). Somehow you are trying to install (or have already installed) `libjack-dev`, which is based on code released two and a half years ago.

The following should get you going:

```
sudo apt-get purge libjack-dev 
sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-dev
```